# How to setup Azure Web apps URL to route via AWS Route53?

Tags: wordpress, azure, amazon-ec2, azure-web-app-service, amazon-route53

I have a WordPress blog which is running on Azure Web-apps (Free-Tier). Earlier this WordPress blog was on AWS-EC2, it also contain the DNS entry in AWS Route53. Something like this:

> blog.xxxxx.com A 54.45.X.X

I have migrated the WordPress blog to Azure Web apps. Azure Web-apps comes with predefined URL something like `xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net.` I have mapped the URL with AWS Route53 as CNAME entry.

> blog.xxxxx.com  CNAME  xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net

After updating the Record Set, it doesn't redirect. Instead I receive a 404 error.

Comment: Why don't you replace xxxxxx with the actual values so we can take a look?

Comment: I can't it's one of my client's blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few more steps to adding a custom domain name to your Azure Web Apps site. You can find the full instructions here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

You're missing two steps:

1. Custom domain names are not supported for free sites. You need to upgrade it to Shared at least.
2. Go to the settings page for your app in the Azure portal and enable the domain name for your web app.